# problem in insert query using mysql and php

Tags: php

The problem is in insert query.If we insert a single data in the db it is inserted for multiple time in that the primary key(auto increment) is increased  but the value give by the user didn't store in db why?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>comment</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
require('db.php');

?>
<form action="db.php" method="get">
    <input type="textarea"  name="textarea" rows="4" value="" >
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>


<?php

 $comment = isset($_GET['textarea']) ? $_GET['textarea'] : '';
 $sql="INSERT INTO comment(comments) VALUES('$comment')";
        mysqli_query($con,$sql);


        ?>


</body>
</html>
```

the actual table name is comment and the column name is comment_id and comments.
if a user  ask some question in textarea(in HTML design) that should be inserted in comments column.

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). **This will take care of any pesky quoting issues that may occur.**

Comment: To improve security, you may prefer to use the `filter_input` function instead of accessing the superglobal variable `$_POST`, `$_GET`, and others. Example: `filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'var')`. See more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not submit the form to the same file you are requiring on line 7.

Rather submit the form to itself. Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>comment</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
require('db.php');

if(!isset($_GET['submit']))
{
?>
<form method="get">
    <input type="textarea"  name="textarea" rows="4" value="" >
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>


<?php
} else {

 $comment = isset($_GET['textarea']) ? $_GET['textarea'] : '';
 $sql="INSERT INTO comment(comments) VALUES('$comment')";
        mysqli_query($con,$sql);

}
        ?>


</body>
</html>
```

Also like @aynber mentioned in the comments, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php), to secure your app a bit.

Comment: Thank you sir. got the value in db.